# Can i call a feature within a feature?

Tags: php, jquery, html, bdd, behat

I have written a feature which test all the nav links on each page of a website.
I would like to test the nav links on each page within other features without writing out the step definitions that as in the feature which tests the nav.

So if i have 'nav nav feature and contact.feature how do i include the nav feature in contact to test the header and footer links on contacts without writing out all the steps for the nav in the contact feature?

```
(# features/membershippurchase.feature)
```

Comment: Do you mean function?

Comment: @default.kramer but he should use proper tag.... I can't see any jQuery in his question and on the *behat* website.

Answer (score 0):

It is not relevant for other features if the navigation is correct or not. That's only relevant to the navigation feature. That one should proof that the navs are correct on each page. Other features, like a contact feature, should only proof that the contact page contains the required widgets (e.g. a contact form).